# Interactive and changable images in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to create a fictional map as a visual representation for a particular community in a video game that I would not disclose.
The map would have multiple landmarks that requires to be drawn a radius around it, creating a circle. This circle should change in color depending on certain events that occurred, often monthly.
The reason why it is in Google Sheets was the data that is being collected from the game is needed to be calculated and graphed alongside the said interactive map.
I can confidently say that no one have perform this sort of thing with Google Sheets before.

My skills are essentially beginner-level, so if there are some topics that are outside the scope of general amateur skillset, please describe it for me.

I first thought that I could simply overlap images together, but images in Google Sheets can't change it's position in the sheets through the app-script, like placing it in a coordinate system. Because there are many landmarks that are needed to be drawn a circle around with multiple different kinds of color existing in the palette, it's not exactly a good idea to have all possible combination of different landmarks or color of the circle and then display one correct one out of hundreds of possibility.

Changing the color can be manually be dealt by hand, as monthly changes are not difficult to perform.

If there are other more suitable program for this job, please let me know!

Comment: I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the image of sample output you expect and your current issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is GIS data ([see GIS community at Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)), and you need to visualize it.

I don’t know what kind of raw data you have but you can probably load it directly to a GIS program like QGIS ([link to site](https://qgis.org/)) to visualize it, or even do things like heat maps or aggregations without need of programming.

If it doesn’t have an specific functionality that you need and there’s no plugin that does so, you can also make a content service ([see documentation on how to do so](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)) that returns a GeoJSON with points on the landmarks with the computed data as extra information. Then I’d use the program to visualize it. This obviously requires programming.

If for some reason you cannot install a program, you could also make a WebApp ([see documentation on how to do so](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)) and use a GIS library ([Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/), for example) to make a visualizate of the data. In this case the data would be fetched via `google.script.run`. This requires even more programming.

### References

- [Content Service (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)
- [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)
- [google.script.run (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run?hl=en)
- [QGIS webpage](https://qgis.org/)
- [Leaflet webpage](https://leafletjs.com/)